# Wrong output from an double operation

Tags: java, double, arithmetic-expressions

I'm a beginner in Java programming. When I coded a simple console app it gave an output which was not what I wanted. My code is:

```
class myClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ballsPlayed = 100;

        double o = (double)(( ballsPlayed / 6 )  + ( ( ballsPlayed % 6) / 10 ));
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```

`( ( ballsPlayed % 6) / 10)` should be 0.4 since remainder of 100/6 is 4 and 4/10 must give 0.4. Then the variable 'o' must give 16.4(16+0.4). But I am getting 16.0 as an output from console. What is the mistake I committed?

Comment: What do you mean by "it gave an output which was not wanted"? Was there an error, was the answer different than you were expecting?

Comment: A double isn't required to have a decimal point when instantiated :) You can declare `double ballsPlayed = 100;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must Typecast the `ballsPlayed` to `double` because `ballsPlayed` is an integer. It returns the integer part of `(ballsPlayed % 6) / 10`. Thus you got 0 except 0.4.

Try this,

```
double o = (double)(( ballsPlayed / 6 )  + ((double) ( ballsPlayed % 6) / 10 ));
```

Here you will get 16 + 0.4 = 16.4

Answer (score 1):

Just change the `ballsPlayed` variable from `int` to

```
double ballsPlayed = 100;
```

this will obviate the need for multiple casts. The output of (( ballsPlayed % 6) / 10 )) will be 0 not 0.4 because the compiler is dealing with an int value.

Answer (score 0):

The output of `(( ballsPlayed % 6) / 10 ))` is 0 not 0.4 because all values in here is `int`. You need one double value for `/` operation to get `double` output. To get desired output change like

```
 ( (double)( ballsPlayed % 6) / 10 ))
```

or

```
(( ballsPlayed % 6) / 10.0 )) // Make 10 as double
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem starts here 
`ballsPlayed / 6`

An integer divided by an integer gives an integer - casting it to double is too late, you'll just get a `double` representation if the truncated result from the first integer division

If you want to get a fractional result from this, you need to cast ( or declare ) one of the numbers involved in the calculation in to a floating point data type.

This is pretty much what every one else has said ....

Answer (score 0):

`ballsPlayed` is int so by default `ballsPlayed/6` will give you int only so that is 16. Similar is the case with `ballsPlayed % 6` which will give int and again division by 10 will give int which will result in 0.

**Here you want the first division to be int and second division to be treated as double..** So just put the casting for second operation as

```
double o = (( ballsPlayed / 6 )  + ( ( (double)ballsPlayed % 6) / 10 ));
```

here the ballsPlayed % 6 will be 4 and (double)ballsPlayed % 6) will be 4.0, a double. You can also do the casting after division

```
double o = (( ballsPlayed / 6 )  + ( (double)( ballsPlayed % 6) / 10 ));
```